# BigQuery authorization

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use the `bq` command line tool to load data into BigQuery from GCS bucket and I receive the following error message:

`BigQuery error in load operation: Access Denied: Job mythical-maxim-293:bqjob_r11765e0cd9ceb52b_000001427694f0e1_1: RUN_JOB`

I was using service account (with private key) for authentication. I followed the following links for granting the service account access level:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/access-control

The service account email was granted WRITE access with the BigQuery dataset and READ access with the GCS bucket.

Note: Adding the service account email as a writer to the project, solved the issue but this is not feasible for my case. I am not allowed to request project level write access but BigQuery and GCS (readonly).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact command you were trying to execute?

Comment: bq \
--service_account 692299006198-o3sg7i6nqp3dc3sa4kjj5voc290t5f77@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--service_account_credential_file ~/.bigquery/identity.xplenty.cred \
--service_account_private_key_file ~/.bigquery/identity.xplenty.p12 \
--service_account_private_key_password notasecret \
--project_id mythical-maxim-293 \
load my_data_set_1.my_table_1 gs://xptest/test.csv

Comment: Did you give your service account read access to the objects in the bucket? Bucket read permission doesn't necessarily imply object read permission.

Comment: Yes, I have. For the same service account, I was able to use gsutil for downloading the csv file: `gsutil cp gs://xptest/test.csv ./test.csv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run the job, the service account must be given at least READ permissions on the project. This is because whoever runs a job in the project can do things that cost the project owner money (e.g. run queries).

To add the service account to the project, go to https://cloud.google.com/console, then click on "Permissions", then "Add member".

Comment: Seems like a problematic approach since granting READ access to a Project can't be limited to specific services (what if my service account is only used for BigQuery loads?). Am I missing anything? I need a way to grant my service account BigQuery load without exposing it to other google cloud services with READ permissions..

Comment: Oh, and another question - Will it be different if I use other authorisation methods (OAuth2 Web Flow for instance)?

Comment: The process is the same if you use OAuth2, however you can restrict the OAuth scope to only allow access to BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jordan.

Will restricting OAuth scope to only allow access to BigQuery still allow that token to run load jobs? Correct me if I am wrong, but the service account authorization is also limited to BigQuery only without that requirement for having READ permissions on the project.

Comment: You will still need to add the service account to the project to be able to run a job; unfortunately there isn't a way around that at the time.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. Granting the service account with READ permissions on the BigQuery dataset project does the job.

Just another small question which you (as GCP authorization team member) should consider: You mentioned that since Load operation requires billing, the account has to be granted with READ permissions. If that is the case, how come it's possible to do Inserts to the BQ dataset without a READ permission to the Project?

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the WRITE permission on the dataset.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#access

This is bad, as WRITE permission imply that you have READ permission. But, for bigquery READ is paid and Load is free. For doing free task, access to paid service should be necessary.

Google must correct this.